# magento 2 , unable to remove fb conversion event code in minicart

Tags: magento2

I've added FB conversion event script in mini cart sidebar, wanted to cancel now and I've tried to remove the script in code and refresh the cache but still, it's showing the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can run below command and check.

> rm -rf var/* pub/static/* generated/*
>
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

Hope it help!